# global_planner is not registered

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-hydro, global-planner, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use the global_planner, I added it in move_base parameters as

```
base_global_planner: global_planner/PlannerCore
```

but it keeps saying this planner is not registered. Is there a special way to register it?

---

These are the errors:

Using the deb (/opt/ros/hydro/share/global_planner)

```
[FATAL] [1390401478.753618530, 223.054000000]: Failed to create the global_planner/PlannerCore planner, are you sure it is properly registered and that the containing library is built? Exception: According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class global_planner/PlannerCore with base class type nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner does not exist. Declared types are  SBPLLatticePlanner carrot_planner/CarrotPlanner goal_passer/GoalPasser iri_bspline_navfn/NavfnROS navfn/NavfnROS
```

If I try using an overlay (catkin_ws/navigation/global_planner)

```
[FATAL] [1390401282.627051354, 30.763000000]: Failed to create the global_planner/PlannerCore planner, are you sure it is properly registered and that the containing library is built? Exception: MultiLibraryClassLoader: Could not create object of class type global_planner::PlannerCore as no factory exists for it. Make sure that the library exists and was explicitly loaded through MultiLibraryClassLoader::loadLibrary()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/120736/global_planner-is-not-registered/) by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 843 on 2014-01-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [avicenna](https://answers.ros.org/users/29922/avicenna/) on 2017-05-25**:
how can u solve your problem. I have same error. İ try to install package which located this link: https://github.com/coins-lab/relaxed_astar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Apparently there's a bug in **bgp_plugin.xml**

This patch: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/pull/161 fixes it

---

Originally posted by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) with karma: 843 on 2014-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2